# Convert MySQL text string with time to date

Tags: mysql, date, str-to-date

I'm trying to convert a date string with time (stored in a varchar field) to a date format. The current strings are in this format: December 23, 2010 13:57

What I need them to be converted to is a standard date format without the time: 2010-12-23

I've tried the following but come up with NULL for the results:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(fieldname, '%Y-%m-%d') AS newdate FROM tablename;
```

Next, I thought maybe I'd have to strip the time off of the string, so I tried:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(fieldname, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(fieldname) - 6), '%Y-%m-%d') AS newdate FROM tablename;
```

and also got NULL for the results.

Am I approaching this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format is this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(fieldname, '%M %e, %Y') AS newdate FROM tablename;
```

where:

- `%M` is the month name (January..December)
- `%e` is the day of the month, numeric 0..31
- `%Y` is the year